# How do i insert different set of database data into powerpoint when i duplicate slides?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am new to vba ppt coding sorry if the question is badly phrased

How do i create mutiple set of slide 1-4 with diff database data inside?

(I can create multiple set but i can't insert database data)

For example :

1st set of 1-4 is data from SeqNo : 1

2nd set of 1-4 is data from SeqNo : 2

My Code:

```
 conn.Open cs

 query = "SELECT  SeqNo, SeqData  from Seqtab ORDER BY SeqNo DESC;"
 rs.Open query, conn

row = 0
Do Until rs.EOF
Dim myPres As Presentation
Dim mySlide As SlideRange
Dim count As Long
Set myPres = ActivePresentation
Dim sldRng As PowerPoint.SlideRange
Set sldRng = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Duplicate
sldRng.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange = rs.Fields("SeqNo ").Value
sldRng.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange = rs.Fields("SeqData").Value
```

Answer (score 1):

If you duplicate a range of slides, you will get a range of slides back so you have define a slide range for your reference

`Dim sldRng as PowerPoint.SlideRange
Set sldRng = ActivePresentation.Slides.Range(Array(1, 2, 3, 4)).Duplicate`

Comment: i receive a error `Method 'Item' of object 'Shapes' Failed`

Comment: My code above does not reference any shapes items so the problem is in the code block you are using.